# Oracle subtracting days and minutes

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I want to subtract "X" days and "X" minutes from sysdate, where the days and minutes are an integer as input parameter. For instance, **10** days and **5** minutes.

I found many examples to subtract either minutes or hours but not a combination of days and minutes.

```
select sysdate - 5 / 24 / 60 from dual -- will retrieve sysdate minus 5 minutes. 
--What about the days?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use an [interval literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221):

```
SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10 00:05' DAY(2) TO MINUTE
FROM   DUAL
```

Or:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
FROM   DUAL
```

Or just use arithmetic:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - 10 /* Days */ - 5 / 24 /60 /* Minutes */
FROM   DUAL
```

Or use [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm):

```
SELECT SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL( 10, 'DAY' ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL( 5, 'MINUTE' )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interval day to minute - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598

```
select sysdate - interval '1 00:05' day to minute from dual
```