# Oracle SQL - How do I arrange my list based on customers' start and end locations?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table and I would like to find out which customers made a trip where his/her start_location is the end_location of another customer who made the trip <= 5 minutes before him/her.

For instance, this is what I have:

```
DT                    Customer_Name       Start_location   End_location    Trip_fare
2019-11-01 08:17:42   Jane                  A                 B            $10
2019-11-01 08:18:02   Mary                  C                 A            $7
2019-11-01 08:18:04   Tom                   B                 D            $12
2019-11-01 08:20:11   Harry                 E                 C            $20
2019-11-01 08:21:22   Alex                  D                 A            $5
2019-11-01 08:24:30   Sally                 C                 B            $8
```

This is what I want:

```
DT                    Customer_Name    Start_location   End_location   
2019-11-01 08:17:42   Jane              A                 B
2019-11-01 08:18:04   Tom               B                 D  (cause Tom's start_location = B = Jane's end_location and the time difference between the 2 trips is within 5 minutes)
2019-11-01 08:21:22   Alex              D                 A
2019-11-01 08:20:11   Harry             E                 C 
2019-11-01 08:24:30   Sally             C                 B
```

Here, Mary has been removed from the list as her start_location = 'C', which is not the end_location of Jane who made a trip <= 5 minutes before her.

My apologies for this 'messy' looking question. Do let me know if you need further clarifications!

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did you forget Mary in the second table or is there a reason she is left out?

Comment: I'm looking at this, and this my question, Harry start_location is E, which is not End_location of another customer, why it showup in the result?

Comment: @JimmyN Harry is the start point of another chain that continues with Sally. Maybe Mary is left out because she is not part of any chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the below table and I would like to find out which customers made a trip where his/her start_location is the end_location of another customer who made the trip <= 5 minutes before him/her.

Your description of the problem suggests `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.end_loc = t.start_loc and
                        t2.dt < t.dt and
                        t2.dt >= t.dt - interval '5' minute
                 );
```

However, this removes Tom, Alex, and Sally.  From how you describe the question, I think this is correct.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a21ee1524beda18f4940d3bb32be85d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

As your query relates to customers from the same table, you'll need a self join. That is, you join the table with itself.

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable JOIN mytable ...
```

To distinguish one "instance" of the table from the other instance, you'll need alias names:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ...
```

And you need join conditions, that is how your two customers are related. In your example this is quite straightforward:

```
SELECT tcust.name  AS name, 
       tother.name AS other_name
  FROM mytable tcust 
  JOIN mytable tother
    ON tcust.start_loc = tother.end_loc
   AND tcust.dt       >= tother.dt - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

However, this query gets a slightly different result. Can you find out why?

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  dt DATE, name VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), start_loc VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
  end_loc VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), fare NUMBER);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:17:42', 'Jane',  'A', 'B', 10);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:18:02', 'Mary',  'C', 'A', 7);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:18:04', 'Tom',   'B', 'D', 12);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:20:11', 'Harry', 'E', 'C', 20);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:21:22', 'Alex',  'D', 'A',  5);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-11-01 08:24:30', 'Sally', 'C', 'B',  8);
```

Result:

```
NAME   OTHER_NAME
Tom    Jane 
Jane   Mary 
Alex   Tom  
Mary   Harry
Sally  Harry
Jane   Alex
```

The substraction of 5 Minutes is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910819/oracle-subtracting-days-and-minutes).

Comment: I think we can get closer to the desired result by a `CONNECT BY` clause, starting with customers who do not have a predecessor and connecting by target and time. But I am too tired to figure out the fine details right now :/